# Output error of the current password correctly

Tags: error-message, password

In the Setting of an account on front-end I've added the possibility to change the password. Please enter your current password, then the new

```
<form id="userform" class="" method="post" accept-charset="UTF-8">

    <input type="hidden" name="action" value="users/saveUser">
    <input type="hidden" name="redirect" value="">
    <input type="hidden" name="userId" value="{{ user.id }}">

    {% macro errorList(errors) %}
        {% if errors %}
            <div class="errors">

                {% for error in errors %}
                    <div>{{ error }}</div>
                {% endfor %}
            </div>
        {% endif %}
    {% endmacro %}

    <input id="password" type="password" autocomplete="off" name="password" class="input-list password" value="">
    <input id="newPassword" type="password" autocomplete="off" name="newPassword" class="input-list password" value="">

    {% if account is defined %}
        {{ errorList(account.getErrors('password')) }} //Current password
        {{ errorList(account.getErrors('password')) }}
        {{ errorList(account.getErrors('newPassword')) }} //New password
        {{ errorList(account.getErrors('newPassword')) }}
    {% endif %}

    <input type="submit" value="Save" class="input-submit">
</form>
```

Mistakes new password displayed and the error of the current password is not displayed, for example if it is wrong page just reboot and the data will not be saved. How to be

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change:

```
{{ errorList(account.getErrors('password')) }} //Current password
```

To:

```
{{ errorList(account.getErrors('currentPassword')) }} //Current password
```